# Find unknown name and surname in opened Word document, copy it and paste into the cell A12 in excel .activesheet with excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation, ms-word

Hello Stackoverflow community.

My goal is to write a macro that finds unknown name (or both names written like so "Firstname Secondname") and surname (or both surnames written like so "Firstsurname-Secondsurname") in previously opened/active Word document - there will be only one Word document opened on the computer at the time. I want to find and copy the name and surname from point 2.

Next the macro should copy this name and paste it into the cell A12 in excel"s .activesheet. Only one excel workbook will be opened on the computer at the time.

The structure of the word document is quite consistent and apart from names and personal/id numbers everything stays the same, but no word bookmarks are created. I've found the text that never changes in point 1. = "REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,".
It's before the name+surname I want to find and copy - I hope it helps.

But also the text "2. " is directly before the name+surname I want to copy and although in the whole contract the string "2. " appears over 20 times, this is the 1st "2. " occurence that precedes name+surname I want to copy and paste into excel's cell.

Name+surname changes all the time, is unknown and has different number of words/characters every time.

[image]

```
Sub FindNames()
    'Variables declaration
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet

    Dim TextToFind As String
    Dim FirstName As String
    Dim Rng As Word.Range
    Dim StartPos As Long
    Dim EndPos As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    TextToFind = "REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,"             'this text length is 21 caracters

    'Assigning object variables
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set ExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.ActiveDocument
    Set MySheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'Set MySheet = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set Rng = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content

    'InStr function returns a Variant (Long) specifying the position of the _
     first occurrence of one string within another.
    StartPos = InStr(1, Rng, TextToFind)          'here we get 1420, we're looking 4 "TextToFind"
    EndPos = InStr(StartPos, Rng, "§ 1. ")        'here we get 2742, we're looking 4 ",00zł"

    If StartPos = 0 Or EndPos = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Client's names were not found!")
    Else
        StartPos = StartPos + Len(TextToFind)     'now start position is reassigned at 1455;
        FirstName = Mid(Rng, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos)

    End If
    'len(Firstname)
End Sub
```

This is the best I can write, but I cannot isolate only name+surname from the bigger variable = `FirstName`.

My version of the code provided by @PeterT, which is not working for me.

```
Rng.SetRange Start:=StartPos, End:=EndPos
    Debug.Print Rng.Paragraphs.Count

    If StartPos = 0 Or EndPos = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Client's names were not found!")
    'finding the paragraphs that follow the TextToFind1
    Else
        For Each Para In Rng.Paragraphs
         'how to identify the second paragraph?
         'these are not .ListParagraphs, they're normal paragraphs  
         'If Para.Range.ListParagraphs.Count = 1 Then
            If Para.Range.Paragraphs.Count = 2 Then
               'how to access the second paragraph?
               'If Para.Range.ListFormat.ListValue = 2 Then
               'Para.Range.Paragraphs(1).Next(Count:=1).Range
               'If Para.Range.Paragraphs.Count = 2 Then
                Debug.Print "Name = " & Para.Range.Words(1) & _
                            ", Surname = " & Para.Range.Words(2)
            End If
        Next Para
    End If
```

I can't access second paragraph and extract the "Michał Łukasz ROESLER" string.

I'd also like to extract "Katarzyna Paula STANISZKIS-KRAWCZYK" from the third paragraph in the `Rng`. Both of them are on the first page of the document.

[image]

Comment: Is your code running in an Excel workbook or in a Word document?

Comment: The code is written and run from Excel VBA editor. I work in Excel. I just need to pull some data from Word doc (which is manually opened only to copy data from it) and paste them into Excel sheet. That's why I need to find and copy data in Word doc - only to paste them into Excel.

Comment: @PeterT It's few hours now I'm trying to understand and adapt the code you provided to my document. It's run from Excel VBA editor. The variables are declared and set. The range is ```Rng.SetRange Start:=StartPos, End:=EndPos``` and has 11 paragraphs. Until this moment I'm sure the first part of the code works fine, but I cannot understand this part ```For Each para ... Next para```. I'll paste it in the bottom of the main post with your name tagged. If you read this comment and you'd like to amend this code I'll be so very grateful. The name we're searching for is in the 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **This answer is deliberately separate from my previous example. That other example
>   is based on finding paragraphs formatted as `ListParagraphs`, and
>   remains valid if your search must include that formatting style.**
>
> This answer assumes the numbered paragraphs are simply regular paragraphs (albeit >indented and numbered). No error checking is performed in this example, e.g. if the >paragraph is not numbered or the names are located elsewhere in the paragraph.

By setting up the `searchRange` in the manner below, you are assured that the first paragraph is the one containing your search term. In this case, it's the paragraph for Item 1. Since the `searchRange` is defined using the search term, you're assured that the name is in the next paragraph. No loop is necessary.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindNames2()
    Dim textToFind As String
    textToFind = "REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,"

    Dim searchArea As Word.Range
    Set searchArea = ThisDocument.Content

    Dim startPos As Long
    Dim endPos As Long
    startPos = InStr(1, searchArea, textToFind)
    If (startPos = 0) Then Exit Sub

    '--- adjust the area to start from where we found the text
    '    until the end of the document
    searchArea.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=searchArea.End

    '--- we want the name at the start of the very next paragraph
    '    (the current paragraph with the text to find is paragraph 1)
    Dim theParagraph As Word.Paragraph
    Set theParagraph = searchArea.Paragraphs(2)

    Dim itemNumber As Long
    Dim firstName As String
    Dim lastName As String
    itemNumber = CLng(Trim(theParagraph.Range.Words(1)))
    firstName = Trim$(theParagraph.Range.Words(3))
    lastName = Trim$(theParagraph.Range.Words(4))

    Debug.Print "Name = " & firstName & " " & lastName & " in Item #" & itemNumber
End Sub
```

A couple things to note from additional example in the OP.

1. The `endPos` may be zero, even if the search text is found. My testing showed that checking the `startPos` was sufficient.
2. When accessing a `Word(3)`, for example, the returned text may have whitespace on one or both sides of the word. Using the `Trim$` function removes that whitespace.
3. You can access the name in the paragraph below by incrementing from `Paragraphs(2)` to `Paragraphs(3)`.

Comment: OP = Original Post

Answer (score 1):

This example code assumes you are executing the macro from the MS Word document.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindNames()
    Dim textToFind As String
    textToFind = "REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,"

    Dim searchArea As Word.Range
    Set searchArea = ThisDocument.Content

    Dim startPos As Long
    Dim endPos As Long
    startPos = InStr(1, searchArea, textToFind)
    If startPos = 0 Then Exit Sub

    '--- adjust the area to start from where we found the text 
    '    until the end of the document
    searchArea.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=searchArea.End

    '--- now find the list paragraphs that follow the text
    Dim para As Word.Paragraph
    For Each para In searchArea.Paragraphs

        '--- identify the list paragraph
        If para.Range.ListParagraphs.Count = 1 Then

            '--- find the second item in the list
            If para.Range.ListFormat.ListValue = 2 Then
                Debug.Print "Name = " & para.Range.Words(1) & _
                            ", Surname = " & para.Range.Words(2)
            End If
        End If
    Next para

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846208/vba-to-find-specific-text-in-word-doc-and-copy-this-text-from-word-doc-into-a-ce

Comment: If I'd like to learn the paragraphs count in ```searchArea``` how would I do that and where would I insert that line? I'm trying Your code now and got a problem - I cannot get out of the ```For Each Para In Rng.Paragraphs``` loop. The ```Para.Range.ListParagraphs.Count = 0``` even after 200 loops.

Comment: These are not ```ListParagraphs```. They are the normal Ones - I don't know how to say it professionally. The numbered list is not enabled on those paragraphs on the first few pages.

Comment: It's few hours now I'm trying to understand and adapt the code you provided to my document. It's run from Excel VBA editor. The variables are declared and set. The range is ```Rng.SetRange Start:=StartPos, End:=EndPos``` and has 11 paragraphs.  Until this moment I'm sure the first part of the code works fine, but I cannot understand this part ```For Each para ... Next para```. I'll paste it in the bottom of the main post with your name tagged. If you read this comment and you'd like to amend this code I'll be so very grateful. The name we're searching for is in the 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is create a `Word.Range`, search the range, then adjust it to capture the names.

```vb
Dim srchRng as Word.Range
Dim thisDoc as Word.Document: Set thisDoc = Word.ActiveDocument

Set srchRange = thisDoc.Content
With srchRange.Find
    .Text = "REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,"
    .Execute
    If .Found = True Then
        srchRange.MoveEndUntil Cset:="."
        srchRange.MoveEnd wdWord, 3

        If srchRange.Words.Last.Next.Text = "-" Then
            srchRange.MoveEnd wdWord, 2
        End If

        Dim nameStart As Long
        nameStart = InStr(1, srchRange.Text, "2. ")
        Dim fullName As String
        fullName = Mid(srchRange.Text, nameStart + 3)
    End If
End With


Debug.Print fullName
```

Comment: Hello @jclasley. I'm currently reading microsoft VBA to digest the code you've provided. Can you please explain ```If Rng.Words.Last.Next.Text = "-" Then
               Rng.MoveEnd wdWord, 2``` I'd be more than grateful. Ahhh, and thank you for answering this second question. Once I understand the code above I'll head right there.

Comment: This is calling bunch of nested properties to say "I want the text of the word following the last word in my range". Your range at this point goes to the first two words in the name, but VBA thinks that things split by hyphens are separate words. We're saying "If the word after our range is a hyphen `"-"` then move the range two words to the right so that it grabs the hyphen and the word following the hyphen. I did this to account for the possibility you mentioned in your question, i.e. a surname that is hyphenated.